# How to pull middle part of the page up on the logo, but keep background down?

Tags: html, css

I tried to have a center part of the page go up onto the logo image. but without the background color. The only way I came up with was hacky way by inserting a an empty space which keeps the background down. I don't even know why this work..

So my questions are, why it works and how to do it less hacky way?

So why does the line: `<!-- push me up workaround --> &nbsp; <!-- push me up workaround -->` allows me to push background down?

Example on page: http://tinyurl.com/kp8clnd

```
<div id="theBodyContent">
    <!-- push me up workaround --> &nbsp; <!-- push me up workaround -->
    <div class="pushMeUp content-interior">
        <div id="theBody" class="content">
            <div class="interior-table">
                <div class="interior-table-cell leftcell">
                    <div class="leftinner">
                        <a href=""><img src="images/interior-directions.png" style="width: 95%; height: auto;"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="interior-table-cell rightcell">
                    <div class="rightinner">
                        Some content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#theBodyContent {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dac79d;
}
.pushMeUp {
    margin-top: -217px;
    background-color: #dac79d;
}
#theBody {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `inline-block` element instead:

```
<div id="theBodyContent">
  <!-- here add a div with display inline block -->
  <div style="display: inline-block;"></div>      
  ...
```

Alternative `<br />` works the same.